# Showing pi bonding through chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig

I've tried to make a diagram which shows pi bonding through chemfig, but I was not successful.
Here is what I want.
[image: pi bonding in google images1]
<sub>(source: [chem1.com](http://www.chem1.com/acad/webtext/chembond/CB-images/dblbond-PH.gif))</sub>

or

[image: pi bonding in google images2]
<sub>(source: [uwaterloo.ca](http://www.science.uwaterloo.ca/~cchieh/cact/fig/ethene.gif))</sub>

Since I was unable to do it with chemfig I decided to do it with tikz.
This is the best I could do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (0,1) and         (.5,0.5) .. (.5,0)
.. controls (.5,-.5) and (0,-1) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (.5,1) and     (-.5,0.5) .. (-.5,0)
.. controls (-.5,-.5) and (.5,-1) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5,2.5)     and (-3,3) .. (-2.5,3)
.. controls (-2,3) and (-1.5,2.5) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5,-2.5)     and (-3,-3) .. (-2.5,-3)
.. controls (-2,-3) and (-1.5,-2.5) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-4,0.5) and     (-5,0.83) .. (-4.5,1.5)
.. controls (-4,2.17) and (-3.5,1.31) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-4,-0.5)     and (-5,-0.83) .. (-4.5,-1.5)
.. controls (-4,-2.17) and (-3.5,-1.31) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5+5,2.5)     and (-3+5,3) .. (2.5,3)
.. controls (-2+5,3) and (-1.5+5,2.5) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5+5,-2.5)     and (-3+5,-3) .. (2.5,-3)
.. controls (-2+5,-3) and (-1.5+5,-2.5) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (4,0.5) and     (5,0.83) .. (4.5,1.5)
.. controls (4,2.17) and (3.5,1.31) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (4,-0.5) and     (5,-0.83) .. (4.5,-1.5)
.. controls (4,-2.17) and (3.5,-1.31) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (4.5,1.5) circle (0.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (4.5,-1.5) circle (.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (-4.5,-1.5) circle (.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (-4.5,1.5) circle (.5);

\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (0,1) and     (.5,0.5) .. (.5,0)
.. controls (.5,-.5) and (0,-1) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (.5,1) and     (-.5,0.5) .. (-.5,0)
.. controls (-.5,-.5) and (.5,-1) .. (2.5,0);


\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-4,0.5) and     (-5,0.83) .. (-4.5,1.5)
.. controls (-4,2.17) and (-3.5,1.31) .. (-2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-4,-0.5)     and (-5,-0.83) .. (-4.5,-1.5)
.. controls (-4,-2.17) and (-3.5,-1.31) .. (-2.5,0);


\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (4,0.5) and     (5,0.83) .. (4.5,1.5)
.. controls (4,2.17) and (3.5,1.31) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=gray,draw,opacity=.7] (2.5,0) .. controls (4,-0.5) and     (5,-0.83) .. (4.5,-1.5)
.. controls (4,-2.17) and (3.5,-1.31) .. (2.5,0);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (4.5,1.5) circle (0.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (4.5,-1.5) circle (.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (-4.5,-1.5) circle (.5);

\shade[shading=ball, ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (-4.5,1.5) circle (.5);


\shade[shading=ball, ball color=black,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5,2.5)     and (-3,3) .. (-2.5,3)
.. controls (0,2) .. (2.5,3)
.. controls (3,3) and (3.5,2.5) .. (2.5,0)
.. controls (1.5,1) .. (0,1)
.. controls (-2,1) .. (-2.5,0);


\shade[shading=ball, ball color=black,draw,opacity=.7] (-2.5,0) .. controls (-3.5,-2.5)     and (-3,-3) .. (-2.5,-3)
.. controls (0,-2) .. (2.5,-3)
.. controls (3,-3) and (3.5,-2.5) .. (2.5,-0)
.. controls (1.5,-1) .. (0,-1)
.. controls (-2,-1) .. (-2.5,-0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: my Diagram]

The end result is quite satisfactory, but

1. A shorter code would be nice
2. I am not sure how to use node and label pi bond and sigma bond(usage of quoate box would also look good), and label the atoms as well

Comment: This reminds me of something I one did: https://www.writelatex.com/read/xmsxvkrcbvjw

Comment: You might want to add the standard settings to your `tikzpicture` environment: `\begin{tikzpicture}[every shade/.append style={shading=ball}]`. Maybe there is still a more efficient way to do it as you have e.g. two symmetry axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to your first question

You can keep your code short by applying for-loops in tikz code, like e.g.:

```
\foreach \i in {-4.5,4.5}
  \foreach \j in {-1.5,1.5}
    \shade[ball color=blue,opacity=0.6] (\i,\j) circle (.5) node{H};
```

### Answer to your second question

It is possible to append at every point a node with some text like in the example above. The best advice that I can give you is to read the introducing examples in the manual or short introduction at [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or ask more details - there is a lot of stuff you might do with nodes...